# Maximum length of the text field increases automatically on Data import in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have an Excel file to import in MS Dynamics CRM 365.

In that file, there is a text field column that contains data of maximum 11 characters. In CRM, the maximum length of that field is 10 characters.

Instead of restricting such records from importing, CRM automatically increases the maximum length of the field in CRM to 11 characters.

So how can we set not to customize the field max length on data import in CRM?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I am not an expert on the CRM Data Import, but I reckon that now you have identified this problem it is easy to workaround using Excel

before you import the file, modify it in Excel to do what you want

2 possibilities
1) you want to import all the records, but just the first 10 characters of the text column:  create a new column, and fill it with the formula LEFT(C2,10)
(If the text is in column C).  And copy the result back to the text column with Paste Values.  Then delete the new column and save the Excel and import

2) you want to omit the rows with more than 10 characters long. Use Filter to choose just the shorter rows, copy them to a new spreadsheet, delete all the rows except the header from the original spreadsheet, and copy-and-paste all the filtered rows back.  Then import that spreadsheet.